# Find and Insert Data with no Duplicate value from two database

Tags: sql-server, database, duplicates

i have 2 identical database with many duplicate value,

now i wanna merge both of database into one database with no duplicate value. i have been create blank database with same schema, now i stuck to sort duplicate value and insert it to new table. here sample my code.

```
use DB3

insert into dbo.user (user_id, name)
select (
select user_id, name 
from DB1.dbo.user
union
select user_id,name
from DB2.dbo.user)
```

but with this way we still have duplicate value in 'user_id' or 'name'. can someone here help me to fix it, insert data with no duplicate value.

Comment: UNION will include the row if any of the column is different. You need to first make sure that one of the column like "user_id" you should make unique, and if for any userid there are multiple names, you need to pick one

Comment: I'm not sure that you are not already getting the behavior you want by using `UNION`, q.v. my answer below.

Comment: please clarify with some sample schema..on how those duplicates are ,are they by user_id or by total row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` operator should automatically remove duplicate records which occur between the two queries in the union.  Hence in:

```
select user_id, name 
from DB1.dbo.user
union
select user_id,name
from DB2.dbo.user
```

If a record with `(id1, name1)` should occur in both `DB1.dbo.user` and `DB2.dbo.user`, then only one such record would appear in the result set.